# Component separated by string crashing app swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an app that converts textField input into an array of Int's by using componentSeparatedByString(",") but when i enter more than one comma in the textfield the app crashes, been trying to find a solution online but no luck, how can i fix this? I can keep it from crashing by checking for characters.first == "," ||characters.last == ",", but not consecutive commas.

```
            enterValueLabel.text = ""

            let circuits = circuitNumbersTextField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

            let circuitNumbers = circuits.map { Int($0)!}

            CircuitColors(circuitNumber: circuitNumbers, phaseColors: circuitPhaseColors )


 if /*circuitNumbersTextField.text!.characters.first != "," || */circuitNumbersTextField.text!.characters.last != "," || (circuitNumbersTextField.text!.characters.first != "," && circuitNumbersTextField.text!.characters.last != ",")
```

Comment: It crashes because you're force unwrapping values with `!` and these values can be nil. Use safe unwrapping instead (that should be the case 99,99% of the time), with `if let ... else ...` for example, that way you can debug where it fails.

Comment: @EricD. Question. In this senario will flatMap unwrap that Int($0) optional?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Yes. Good idea.

Comment: So i can't check for a condition of ",,", i've tried using the optional as you stated above but that causes problems when converting to an array of Int's.

Comment: @AngelCaro, Eric isn't telling you to *use* an optional, **you already are**. He's telling you to *unwrap* them safely. When you use **!** you're force unwrapping. If the value is *nil*, the **!** will cause your application to crash. Please read about optioanls: http://ericcerney.com/swift-guard-statement/

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I could make a quick answer for OP but, given your comment about flatMap, I thought you were going to do it so I didn't. Are you? If not, I will. :)

Comment: You can @EricD. I don't know the code well enough to anticipate what it will do on his end, your intuition is probably better.

Comment: I get the error cannot convert [()] to value [Int] when using the optional you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I would do to make your code work. What is important here is the general idea, not the specific example I'm using (although it should work for you).

First, let's safely unwrap the text label:

```
if let text = circuitNumbersTextField.text {

}
```

Now that we avoid using `circuitNumbersTextField.text!` we know that an error wouldn't come from there.

Then we cut the sentence in components:

```
if let text = circuitNumbersTextField.text {
    let circuits = text.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

}
```

We use `flatMap` to safely unwrap the Optionals returned by `Int()`:

```
if let text = circuitNumbersTextField.text {
    let circuits = text.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    let circuitNumbers = circuits.flatMap { Int($0) }
    // circuitNumbers will only contain the successfully unwrapped values
}
```

Your code snippet:

```
if let text = circuitNumbersTextField.text {
    let circuits = text.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    let circuitNumbers = circuits.flatMap { Int($0) }
    if (circuits.first != "," && circuits.last != ",") || circuits.first != "," || circuits.last != "," {
        // condition is met
    } else {
        // condition is not met
    }
}
```

You can now safely use `circuitNumbers` in this code block without crashing.

Comment: nice explanation, I wasn't positive how flatMap would handle the Int($0). +1

Comment: @EricD. Thank you that cleared up a lot of confusion new to programming(3 months) ended up using it like this